# Rails 6 Complex Form with nested objects collection_select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Would be super grateful if anyone had any insights into what I should be doing that I'm not already doing.

db/schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.bigint "cell_number"
    t.boolean "sms_daily"
    t.string "initials"
    t.string "remember_token"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.boolean "vacation_mode", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"
  end

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "comments"
    t.integer "author_id", null: false
    t.boolean "draft", default: true
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_schedules_on_author_id"
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "schedule_id", null: false
    t.integer "order"
    t.string "site"
    t.string "note"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "start_hour"
    t.integer "start_minute"
    t.string "user_initials"
    t.boolean "block"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["schedule_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_schedule_id"
  end
```

app/model/schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms
  ...
end
```

app/model/room.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :schedule
  ...
end
```

app/views/schedule/new.hthl.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create Schedule') %>
<h1>Create Schedule</h1>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <%= form_with(model: @schedule, local: true) do |f| %>

        <div class="field">

          <%= f.fields_for :rooms, html: {class: 'form-inline' } do |r| %>

            <div class="room-title" id="<%="#{r.object[:site]}-#{r.object[:name].delete(' ')}" unless r.object[:name] == nil %>">
              <%= "#{r.object[:site]} #{r.object[:name]}"%>
              <%= r.hidden_field :site, value: r.object[:site] %>
              <%= r.hidden_field :name, value: r.object[:name] %>
              <% unless (r.object[:name] == "CHARGE" || r.object[:name] == "CO-CHARGE" || r.object[:site] == "ON_CALL" || r.object[:site] == "On-Call TODAY (Sunday or Holiday)") %>
                <br/>
                <%= r.label :start_hour %>
                <%= r.number_field :start_hour, in: 0..24, step: 1 %>
                <br/>
                <%= r.label :start_minute %>
                <%= r.number_field :start_minute, in: 0..60, step: 1 %>
              <% end %>
              <%= r.collection_select(:user_initials,User.all.map(&:initials).sort.unshift("-- late start").collect,:initials,:initials, include_blank: true) %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <%= f.submit "Save Schedule and Review", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary",  input_html: { :tabindex => autotab  } %>
        </div>  
      <% end %>
     </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

I'd like for the form to present a choice of all the User's initials to be assigned to the room's user_initials, also offer the choice of not designating anyone's initials with "-- late start" as well as leaving the initials blank for an empty room.

When I deploy my code to heroku the schedule/new page generates a "We're sorry, something went wrong" error and the logs say:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `initials' for "-- late start":String):
```

I got this all working in Rails 4 using simple_form but heroku will no longer support the stack that I deployed the site to starting in November, 2020, and heroku's new stack's won't use the old ruby version from the original site.  I'm rewriting the code in Rails 6 which simple_form doesn't work for.

Thanks in advance for your consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection_select` works on a collection of objects and will look for the `initials` method on each object.

when you do this...

```
<%= r.collection_select(:user_initials,User.all.map(&:initials).sort.unshift("-- late start").collect,:initials,:initials, include_blank: true) %>
```

You're just creating an array of strings, and you're prepending another string to the array, and the strings don't have an initials method.

Better might be just to use `select`

```
<%= r.select(:user_initials, options_for_select(User.all.pluck(:initials).sort.unshift("-- late start"), r.object.user_initials), include_blank: true) %>
```

You can use `collection_select`, it must be ALL user objects, so you could temporarily create a user with initials '--late start', something like...

```
<%= r.collection_select(:user_initials, User.order(:initials).to_a.prepend(User.new(initials: "-- late start")), :initials, :initials, include_blank: true) %>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you so much.  I forgotten how I got this working initially and likely only had a most superficial understanding in the first place.  I believe that other newbies will likely have similar problems and that your answer will help others.  That said, as of writing this comment, my question has -3 votes which perhaps is a comment on my ignorance.  Any thoughts on how I can make my question better or why the down votes?

Comment: I've reviewed the reason at least one person put forward regarding why the question should be closed, and they state it's because the problem is not reproducible or caused by a typo, which I'm not necessarily in agreement with. It might be that too much information is presented... it helps to know the fields and the relations and of course the `collection_select` is critical to understanding the problem, the rest is probably a bit dense for someone to read.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and analysis, @SteveTurczyn.  As dense as my question was it came from not really understanding how collection_select and select work.  I agree that your answer clears that up in the specific case and also helps newbies understand better how all rails methods might work.  I suspect others searching for "Rails 6 form collection_select not working" as I did will gain a great deal from your answer, too.  With that in mind, I'll keep it up for now.  If folks don't find value from it and upvote, I'll delete it.  Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: I don't think anyone is requiring you to delete your question.  There's a close vote (as I said) but only one, so it's not going to be actioned on unless more people vote for it and at this stage it doesn't look like that's going to happen.  I appreciate that you want to make the best question you can, but again the voters have moved on. I think best is to keep on posting questions and answers.  It all works itself in the end!